Compare the JSON response of a request with a JSON schema
I'm using the IntelliJ Http client to perform some requests and some simple tests. However, I have a couple of JSON schema files that define how the response of a specific endpoint should look like.
That's way, I'm looking for ways how I can compare the response to a JSON schema. So far I couldn't find one. Is there?
